# Show that if $n\geq 5$ then $1!+2!+3!+\ldots+n!\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, factorial, legendre-symbol

Show that if $n\geq 5$ then $1!+2!+3!+\ldots+n!\equiv 3\pmod{5}$
I found this problem  in Legendre Symbol Section, but I can't find relationship between $n!$ between factorial and Legendre Symbol.
Anyone can give a hint or some part of proof?

Comment: **Hint:** What is $n!\pmod{5}$ for any $n\geq 5$?  (Is $5$ a multiple of $n!$ for $n\geq 5$?)  What terms actually contribute then to the sum modulo five?

Comment: @JMoravitz means: Is $n!$ a multiple of $5$ for $n\ge5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that for $n\geq 5$ then 
$$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+\dots +n!=33+5\cdot(4!+\dots +(n!/5))\equiv 33\equiv 3\pmod{5}.$$
Note that for $n\geq 5$, the number $(4!+\dots +(n!/5))$ is an integer because $5$ divides $k!$ for $5\leq k\leq n$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $n!\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ for all $n\ge 5$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: you don't need the Legendre symbol. Note that from $5!$ all factorials are multiple of $10$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{4}k!=33.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
(&1! &+ &2! &+ &3! &+ &\ldots &+ &n!) &\bmod &5 = \\
=\Big((&1! \bmod 5) &+ (&2! \bmod 5) &+ (&3! \bmod 5) &+ &\ldots &+ (&n! \bmod 5)\Big) &\bmod &5
\end{align}

Calculate first few terms and see what happens.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$