# How to prove that the sum $1!+2!+...+n! \equiv 0 \pmod 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, factorial

I understand the divisibility rule, if the sum of a numbers digits are divisible by $9$, the number is divisible by $9$. I'm not sure how to integrate that, or if I even should.
Could I assume that for any $n>8$, $n!$ is divisible by $9$. And thus the sum of all $n!$ where $n>8$ would too be divisible by $9$?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Certainly, if $n\ge 9$ then $9$ is a factor in $1\times2\times3\cdots\times n=n!$

Comment: Yes, $n!$ is divisible by $9$ if $n\ge 9$. But you still have to deal with the positive integers $1,2,\ldots,8$.

Comment: In fact, n! = 0(mod 9) for n > 5. You only need to check for 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5!

Comment: Here is somewhat similar older problem: [Show that if $n\geq 5$ then $1!+2!+3!+\ldots+n!\equiv 3 \pmod{5}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936733).

Comment: On an unrelated note, this post on meta is related to a post of yours (which is now deleted): [Cleaned up a mess of a question for user just to have it deleted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32779).

Comment: But it's not true.  Fr $n=1,2,4$ you do not have the result.  Yes, you can assume that if $n\ge 9$ then $n!= 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*\color{red}9*.....*n$ is divisible by $9$.  But you can also assume that if $n \ge 6$ then $n!=1*2*\color{red}3*4*5*\color{red}6$ is also divisible by $9$.  So the only thing you have to prove is that $1! +2!+3!+4!+5!\equiv 0 \pmod 9$.  Can you do that?

Comment: But I *DO* have to point out that the statement simply is *NOT* true because it isn't true for $n=1,2,4$.  If we want to assume it is true for *most* values you **must** specify that the statement is true for all $n\ge 5$.  Otherwise if it is not true for one single value of $n$ it is simply  not true.

Answer (score 2):

This statement isn't true for $n=1$ since $1!=1$, nor for $n=2$ since $1!+2!=3$.

But for $n=3$, $1!+2!+3!=9\equiv 0$ (mod 9).

This is again not true $n=4$, since $1!+2!+3!+4!=33\equiv 6$ (mod 9).

But for $n=5$, $1!+2!+3!+4!+5!=153\equiv 0$ (mod 9).

Then $m!=0$ (mod 9) for all $m\geq 6$. Therefore, for $n\geq 6$, $1!+\dots+n!\equiv 1!+2!+3!+4!+5!\equiv 0$ (mod 9).

Comment: use `$\pmod$` to indicate $6=2 \pmod4$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**

If $n\ge 6$ then

\begin{align}
n!
&=1\cdot 2\cdot \color{red}{3}\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot \color{red}6\cdot \;\cdots\;\cdot n
= \color{red}9\cdot (1\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 2\cdot\;\cdots\; \cdot n).
\end{align}

**Hint 2**

$$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!=153=\color{red}9\cdot 17.$$

Answer (score 0):

But it's not true for $n= 1,2$

It is for $n=3$ by examination.  $1! +2! +3! = 1+2 +6=9$.

And $4! = 24$ is not divisible by $9$ but $1!+2!+3!$ is, then it can't be true for $n=4$ (and by examination for $n=4$ we git $(1!+2! +3!) + 4! = 9 + 24 = 33$).

As $4! \equiv 24 \equiv 6\pmod 9$ then $5!\equiv 6*5\equiv 30\equiv 3\pmod 9$ so $(1!+2!+3!)+4!+5! \equiv 0 + 6 + 3\equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

And for any $n\ge 6$ we have $3\times 6=18|n!$ so for all $n\ge 6$ we have $9|n!$ so
as $(1!+2! +3!) + (4! + 5!) + 6! +......... + n! \equiv (0) + (6 + 3) + 0 + ....... + 0\equiv 0 \pmod 9$.

but it's not true for $n=1,2,4$.